# Jmeter - Load Testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Use Case :-

We have an application which can have multiple users logged in simultaneously on a single database or multiple users logged in on multiple databases . The relationship can be 1:M , M:M or M:1 . The issue is we have a very rigorous Business Logic which authenticates these users before letting them log in . Each user will have a token of its own , plus generate his own session accordingly . I cannot fake user's as the app under test will not let it Log In .

I can put up a Load test using some authentic users that are already present in a single database and generate load using HTTP Thread - VM users from different machines and make the session go up periodically .

How do I go for this specific condition - **Test for 5x - 150K concurrent Users, 250k Sessions/min** . I cannot have that many database present which will give me a window of 150k concurrent Users . Please advise .

Answer (score 0):

1. If the app allows concurrent logins it might be one option, like you have X pairs of credentials in the CSV file and the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) set up for reading these credentials. By default each thread will read next line on next iteration so if the app won't kick out the previously logged in guy it might be a viable solution.
2. Another option is login once and save the token/session into a JMeter Property, JMeter Properties are global and can be read by multiple virtual users, it can be done using i.e. [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)
3. The best solution would be generating as many test users in the system as you need because each JMeter thread must represent real user using a [real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) as close as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Generating session is not an issue , but you cannot have data for 150k concurrent users  . Plus there are conditions such as - what will we target multiple databases or a single one as we have a provision for both in our target app . Need an answer where some one would have executed a use case like this one . I could set userid's , password and other required information in CSV file and later read data from it for each user . But the question is how many users , I cannot create 150k users and then set each one for each iteration . Is there a way around it .